# i need help i have problem with sub option problem how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html

after select bmw and select option m5 option. m5 is not showing how to fix this problem ?

i need select bmw and sub option m5 ?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>

<div>
    <select>
        <option value="">select brand</option>
        <option value="2594">bmw</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="2594 box">
    <select name="xfield[bmw]">
    <option value="0">114</option>
    <option value="1">116</option>
    <option value="2">118</option>
    <option value="3">120</option>
    <option value="4">123</option>
    <option value="5">125</option>
    <option value="6">128</option>
    <option value="7">130</option>
    <option value="8">135</option>
    <option value="9">214</option>
    <option value="10">216</option>
    <option value="11">218</option>
    <option value="12">220</option>
    <option value="13">225</option>
    <option value="14">228</option>
    <option value="15">315</option>
    <option value="16">316</option>
    <option value="17">318</option>
    <option value="18">320</option>
    <option value="19">320 GranTurismo</option>
    <option value="20">323</option>
    <option value="21">324</option>
    <option value="22">325</option>
    <option value="23">328</option>
    <option value="24">330</option>
    <option value="25">335</option>
    <option value="26">418</option>
    <option value="27">420</option>
    <option value="28">425</option>
    <option value="29">428</option>
    <option value="30">430</option>
    <option value="31">435</option>
    <option value="32">518</option>
    <option value="33">520</option>
    <option value="34">523</option>
    <option value="35">524</option>
    <option value="36">525</option>
    <option value="37">528</option>
    <option value="38">530</option>
    <option value="39">535</option>
    <option value="40">540</option>
    <option value="41">545</option>
    <option value="42">550</option>
    <option value="43">628</option>
    <option value="44">630</option>
    <option value="45">633</option>
    <option value="46">635</option>
    <option value="47">640</option>
    <option value="48">645</option>
    <option value="49">650</option>
    <option value="50">725</option>
    <option value="51">728</option>
    <option value="52">730</option>
    <option value="53">732</option>
    <option value="54">735</option>
    <option value="55">740</option>
    <option value="56">745</option>
    <option value="57">750</option>
    <option value="58">760</option>
    <option value="59">840</option>
    <option value="60">850</option>
    <option value="61">i3</option>
    <option value="62">i8</option>
    <option value="63">M1</option>
    <option value="64">M135</option>
    <option value="65">M235</option>
    <option value="66">M3</option>
    <option value="67">M4</option>
    <option value="68">M5</option>
    <option value="69">M550</option>
    <option value="70">M6</option>
    <option value="71">X1</option>
    <option value="72">X3</option>
    <option value="73">X4</option>
    <option value="74">X5</option>
    <option value="75">X6</option>
    <option value="76">X6M</option>
    <option value="77">Z1</option>
    <option value="78">Z3</option>
    <option value="79">Z4</option>
    <option value="80">Z8</option>
</select>
</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, per your own snippet, M5 is an option. Can you clarify your exact issue?

Comment: after selecting bmw and m5 or m6 option is hiding hide i need show sub option

Comment: It's not just m5 or m6 its all options. You are hiding it per your code.

Comment: yes i now and i need show sub option m5 after selecting and not hiding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because you are hiding the select in your .change function. The way you currently have it written, your .change is going to fire for every select on the page. That isn't what you want here based on your issue.

If you don't want to hide the second box you either need to assign and id or class to the first select or you could use the :first selector.

Example: This example shows with the :first selector.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select:first").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>

<div>
    <select>
        <option value="">select brand</option>
        <option value="2594">bmw</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="2594 box">
    <select name="xfield[bmw]">
    <option value="0">114</option>
    <option value="1">116</option>
    <option value="2">118</option>
    <option value="3">120</option>
    <option value="4">123</option>
    <option value="5">125</option>
    <option value="6">128</option>
    <option value="7">130</option>
    <option value="8">135</option>
    <option value="9">214</option>
    <option value="10">216</option>
    <option value="11">218</option>
    <option value="12">220</option>
    <option value="13">225</option>
    <option value="14">228</option>
    <option value="15">315</option>
    <option value="16">316</option>
    <option value="17">318</option>
    <option value="18">320</option>
    <option value="19">320 GranTurismo</option>
    <option value="20">323</option>
    <option value="21">324</option>
    <option value="22">325</option>
    <option value="23">328</option>
    <option value="24">330</option>
    <option value="25">335</option>
    <option value="26">418</option>
    <option value="27">420</option>
    <option value="28">425</option>
    <option value="29">428</option>
    <option value="30">430</option>
    <option value="31">435</option>
    <option value="32">518</option>
    <option value="33">520</option>
    <option value="34">523</option>
    <option value="35">524</option>
    <option value="36">525</option>
    <option value="37">528</option>
    <option value="38">530</option>
    <option value="39">535</option>
    <option value="40">540</option>
    <option value="41">545</option>
    <option value="42">550</option>
    <option value="43">628</option>
    <option value="44">630</option>
    <option value="45">633</option>
    <option value="46">635</option>
    <option value="47">640</option>
    <option value="48">645</option>
    <option value="49">650</option>
    <option value="50">725</option>
    <option value="51">728</option>
    <option value="52">730</option>
    <option value="53">732</option>
    <option value="54">735</option>
    <option value="55">740</option>
    <option value="56">745</option>
    <option value="57">750</option>
    <option value="58">760</option>
    <option value="59">840</option>
    <option value="60">850</option>
    <option value="61">i3</option>
    <option value="62">i8</option>
    <option value="63">M1</option>
    <option value="64">M135</option>
    <option value="65">M235</option>
    <option value="66">M3</option>
    <option value="67">M4</option>
    <option value="68">M5</option>
    <option value="69">M550</option>
    <option value="70">M6</option>
    <option value="71">X1</option>
    <option value="72">X3</option>
    <option value="73">X4</option>
    <option value="74">X5</option>
    <option value="75">X6</option>
    <option value="76">X6M</option>
    <option value="77">Z1</option>
    <option value="78">Z3</option>
    <option value="79">Z4</option>
    <option value="80">Z8</option>
</select>
</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
```

Or you can assign an id/class to the select.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#typeSelect").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>

<div>
    <select id="typeSelect">
        <option value="">select brand</option>
        <option value="2594">bmw</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="2594 box">
    <select name="xfield[bmw]">
    <option value="0">114</option>
    <option value="1">116</option>
    <option value="2">118</option>
    <option value="3">120</option>
    <option value="4">123</option>
    <option value="5">125</option>
    <option value="6">128</option>
    <option value="7">130</option>
    <option value="8">135</option>
    <option value="9">214</option>
    <option value="10">216</option>
    <option value="11">218</option>
    <option value="12">220</option>
    <option value="13">225</option>
    <option value="14">228</option>
    <option value="15">315</option>
    <option value="16">316</option>
    <option value="17">318</option>
    <option value="18">320</option>
    <option value="19">320 GranTurismo</option>
    <option value="20">323</option>
    <option value="21">324</option>
    <option value="22">325</option>
    <option value="23">328</option>
    <option value="24">330</option>
    <option value="25">335</option>
    <option value="26">418</option>
    <option value="27">420</option>
    <option value="28">425</option>
    <option value="29">428</option>
    <option value="30">430</option>
    <option value="31">435</option>
    <option value="32">518</option>
    <option value="33">520</option>
    <option value="34">523</option>
    <option value="35">524</option>
    <option value="36">525</option>
    <option value="37">528</option>
    <option value="38">530</option>
    <option value="39">535</option>
    <option value="40">540</option>
    <option value="41">545</option>
    <option value="42">550</option>
    <option value="43">628</option>
    <option value="44">630</option>
    <option value="45">633</option>
    <option value="46">635</option>
    <option value="47">640</option>
    <option value="48">645</option>
    <option value="49">650</option>
    <option value="50">725</option>
    <option value="51">728</option>
    <option value="52">730</option>
    <option value="53">732</option>
    <option value="54">735</option>
    <option value="55">740</option>
    <option value="56">745</option>
    <option value="57">750</option>
    <option value="58">760</option>
    <option value="59">840</option>
    <option value="60">850</option>
    <option value="61">i3</option>
    <option value="62">i8</option>
    <option value="63">M1</option>
    <option value="64">M135</option>
    <option value="65">M235</option>
    <option value="66">M3</option>
    <option value="67">M4</option>
    <option value="68">M5</option>
    <option value="69">M550</option>
    <option value="70">M6</option>
    <option value="71">X1</option>
    <option value="72">X3</option>
    <option value="73">X4</option>
    <option value="74">X5</option>
    <option value="75">X6</option>
    <option value="76">X6M</option>
    <option value="77">Z1</option>
    <option value="78">Z3</option>
    <option value="79">Z4</option>
    <option value="80">Z8</option>
</select>
</div>
    <div class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
    <div class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
```

There are 20 ways to skin this cat, you just need to limit your $(select) scope a bit.

Comment: @ZuraKushitashvili no worries, select as answer if it helped you.